# How to remove noise from a white region, without losing the shape of the white region

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

Here's the image:

[image]

I want to remove the noise within the white region without losing the shape of the white region. I've tried dilation, but that effects the shape of the white region. I've also tried dilation followed by erosion, and it's the same problem - the shape of the white region gets affected.

Comment: You might try using some kind of edge-detection algorithm to find the outline of the white region, then just fill it white.  It looks like the image has black noise near the border, which is going to make it inherently more difficult to distinguish noise from the background in those areas.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a shot! Laplacian will probably detect the edges well.

Answer (score 0):

If the black region is really as clean as this appears, you might want to try selecting the large black region, e.g. with flood-fill, and just setting the inverse to white.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear about what counts as "noise". The dark stuff inside the oval doesn't look like pure noise to me.

Anyway:

You mentioned preserving the border edges. The go-to filter for removing impulsive noise from an image while preserving edges is the median filter.
Here's some python that does this with your image

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread
from scipy.ndimage.filters import median_filter
img = imread("your-image.jpg")
filtered = median_filter(img, size=20)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(filtered)
plt.show()
```

20 is an unusually large filter size (and takes awhile to execute), I chose it to exaggerate the effect on your image. Tiny flecks are removed, and extreme values (black or white) are replaced with greys. Sharp edges are preserved. There's still plenty of non-white stuff left after this operation though.

[image: image after a 20x20 median filter]